# How to read a module from 2 folder upstream using pathlib python

Tags: python, operating-system, pathlib

I have a module named `cloudera` in the folder `parent`. The structure looks like this:

```
--parent
   --cloudera
      --__init__.py
      --cloudera.py
   --subfolder
      --subfolder_child
         --importing_script.ipynb
```

I would like to import the connect function from the `cloudera` module into my `importing_script.ipynb` notebook without changing the cwd but it's not working. My solution was this:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path.cwd()
sys.path.insert(1, path.parent.parent.absolute().resolve())

from cloudera import connect
```

However clearly it is not recognising the path from `sys`:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cloudera'
```

My cwd is:
`WindowsPath('c:/parent/subfolder/subfolder_child')`

Maybe I am misunderstanding path but could someone explain to me why this does not work?

Comment: I would try `sys.path.append("../..")`